# `undo-tree-mode` only goes back a small number of steps when using Ensime, then "no further undo information"

Tags: spacemacs, undo-tree-mode, ensime

When using `undo-tree-undo` in Spacemacs v 300 in `ensime-mode`, I will run into "No further undo information" after a small number of steps --- just around five or so.

I have the following variables set:

`undo-no-redo` nil

`undo-limit` 80000

`undo-in-region` nil

`undo-tree-mode` t

`undo-outer-limit` 12000000

`undo-extra-outer-limit` nil

I am unable to find any Ensime specific variables controlling undo behavior.

How can I maintain a larger undo tree when using Ensime?

Comment: The function `undo-tree-discard-history` contains a doc-string that states:  "*Discard undo history until we're within memory usage limits
set by `undo-limit`, `undo-strong-limit` and `undo-outer-limit`.".  Due to a long-standing bug, the author of `undo-tree` stated in one of the emails on the bug reports that `undo-tree-enable-undo-in-region` should be set to `nil`.  Other than those pointers, I cannot think of another reason why your undo history is being discarded or is otherwise inaccessible (e.g., `undo-tree-enable-undo-in-region` is non-nil and your region is active ...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be mitigated on the current develop branch because those limits were increased by 10X.
When using undo-tree these variables are increased:

```
undo-limit 800000 ;; previously 80000
undo-strong-limit 12000000 ;; previously 120000
undo-outer-limit 120000000 ;; previously 12000000
```

The change is at: https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/commit/dcb4da02a8758e7cb700d69689670b85024b068d

Comment: Welcome to emacs.SE!  It would be nice to include a quick summary of the changes in addition to the link.

Comment: Okay, added some details!